# Linux CentOS - ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts:18:42 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@app/modules/

Tags: linux, angular9

I am getting the following error when I am running the build command in CesntOS, but same command works for Windows Server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JBMt.png)

this is my angular version
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CSWV.png)

Comment: 1. please paste code as text instead of image. 2. did you install dependencies (`npm install` or something like that)?